# Class 'ServiceProvider' not found, can't autload serviceprovider

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to learning laravel package development I had write laravel package by following some tutorials but can't register its service provider in my app. I had upload my package to github. here is my repo https://github.com/zohaibhassan156/laravel-paysimple

Add this in my main composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
  "App\\": "app/",
  "ZohaibHassan156\\LaravelPaySimple\\": "zohaibhassan156/laravel-paysimple/src/"
}
```

and this in my config/app/php

```
    \ZohaibHassan156\LaravelPaySimple\PaySimpleServiceProvider::class,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoloader directories in packages are relative to the directory containing the `composer.json` file - so you don't need to specify the package directory as part of the autoload path.

Also,  if this is a package,  you don't want to specify the App namespace could this could cause a conflict with the app using the package.

So your PSR-4 setting in your package just needs to be:

```
"psr-4": {
  "ZohaibHassan156\\LaravelPaySimple\\": "src/"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got stuck from past 2 days.  Finally your post help me out